# Transform fields to list using jolt

Tags: java, json, transformation, jolt

I'am working on updating my jolt spec to generate the right output. I've done a first try but unfortunately there something missing in my spec in order to obtain a good result.

This is my json input

```json
{
  "id": 111,
  "uuid": "b4915b22-d8c0-47bd-832c-18c0",
  "testKey1[xxx]": "identifier_1234",
  "testKey2[yyyy]": "identifier_14",
  "name": "name1",
  "testValue1[xxx]": "10",
  "testValue2[yyy]": "12",
  "address": "S2271",
  "updateTime": "2024-01-18T10:35:00Z"
}
```

And this is my jolt spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "uuid": "idBus",
      "id": "idTech",
      "name": "title",
      "address": "location",
      "updateTime": "lastUpdated",
      "testValue*": "myList&.value",
      "testKey*": "myList&.code"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "myList*": "myListOfFields[]"
    }
  }
]
```

Actual i have this output

```json
{
  "idBus": "b4915b22-d8c0-47bd-832c-18c0",
  "idTech": 111,
  "title": "name1",
  "location": "S2271",
  "lastUpdated": "2024-01-18T10:35:00Z",
  "myListOfFields": [
    {
      "value": "identifier_1234"
    },
    {
      "value": "identifier_14"
    },
    {
      "code": "10"
    },
    {
      "code": "12"
    }
  ]
}
```

My desired output to be like

```json
{
  "idBus": "b4915b22-d8c0-47bd-832c-18c0",
  "idTech": 111,
  "title": "name1",
  "location": "S2271",
  "lastUpdated": "2024-01-18T10:35:00Z",
  "myListOfFields": [
    {
      "code": "identifier_1234",
      "value": "10"
    },
    {
      "code": "identifier_14",
      "value": "12"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any missed piece in order to achieve the desired output ?
Any help would be appreciate

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might handle the issue like this :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "uuid": "idBus",
      "id": "&Tech",
      "name": "title",
      "address": "location",
      "updateTime": "lastUpdated",
      "test*ue*\\[*": "mLOF&(0,2).value",
      "test*ey*\\[*": "mLOF&(0,2).code" // 2nd replacement from the current(0th) level 
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "mLOF*": "myListOfFields[]"
    }
  }
]
```

where the trick is to separate by **`&(0,2)`** identifiers in order to get the ordinals **`1`**, **`2`** within the **`testValue..[...]`** expressions.

**Edit** :

You could add the following spec to the end in order to convert the format of the **`values`** to **Double** :

```json
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "myListOfFields": {
        "*": {
          "value": "=toDouble"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Barbaros, i appreciate your help it sticks exactly to my need. however is there a way to force the value to be a double ?

Comment: The following will output the same result: `"testValue*\\[*": "mLOF1&(0,1).value"` and `"testKey*\\[*": "mLOF1&(0,1).code"`.  The crux is to produce the same `mLOF[X]` that will aggregate the corresponding `code` and `value` fields, where [X] is the extracted index. Otherwise both fields will be treated as separate elements in the underlying list.

Comment: just added the case @Yawyaw1

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thanks, apreciate your help !!